# Form is always invalid in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems very trivial, so I'm sorry if I just missed something, but I can't figure it out.

I want to enable my button which sends data using AJAX when form is valid, but the button is always disabled.

Have a look:

```
<form name="UserReg" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="user_name"
                                data-ng-model="UserName"
                                ng-maxlength=20
                                placeholder="Name"
                                required />

            <div data-ng-messages="UserReg.user_name.$error"
                 data-ng-show="UserReg.user_name.$touched">

                 <div data-ng-messages-include="angular_app/validation/form_messages.html"></div>

            </div>
        </div>


       <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <button type="button" name="add_user"
                                    class="top-menu-button"
                                    data-ng-click="AddUser()"
                                    ng-disabled="UserReg.$invalid">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg padding-r-5"></i> Add User
            </button>
        </div>

</form>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should enclose the value of `ng-maxlength` in double quotes.
Second, Since you have `required` attribute on the input field, The form will become valid only if the input field has some value (type something in it & the form will become valid).

Otherwise if not necessary remove the `required` attribute from the input field.

Comment: hmmm, I've found the solution. As you can see I've got form_messages.html file there. I didn't have handled "maxlength" in it and this caused the problem, when I add element with ng-message="maxlength" now it works!

Comment: Indeed, looks like the missing quotes around "ng-maxlength" broke something in Angular, when testing adding them caused this to work properly.

Comment: @pavon147 Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: It didn't. I just add ng-message="maxlength" to my form_messages.html file without doing anything you mentioned, but I voted up your answer, because has useful info.

Comment: @pavon147 What you are saying is wrong. Adding ng-message="maxlength"  to form_messages.html will only show validation message & it does not make the form valid. Thanks for up-vote though.